# What is the default value of the IsReadyToPayRequest.existingPaymentMethodRequired property?

Tags: google-pay

The `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object is marked as optional but the documentation does not state what the property's default value is.

What value does this property fall back to if I don't specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property's default value, at the time of writing, is `false`.

You can validate this by calling the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) method with an [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object which omits the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property and with the following setup:

1. The Google Pay environment is set to [PRODUCTION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION).
2. The `IsReadyToPayRequest.allowedAuthMethods` array is set to `["PAN_ONLY","CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]`.
3. Neither your Android device nor your Google account has a payment method added to it.

You will see that the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) method returns `true` with this setup just as it does when the `IsReadyToPayRequest.existingPaymentMethodRequired` property is specified and set to `false`.